# UIScrollView programmatically add buttons and scroll

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I'm new to ios and Objective-C. Please be a little bit patient with me.

THe functionality in my app, which I'm trying to develop, is a small scrolling toolbar, which contains several buttons, state toggling buttons. Also there is another button above the toolbar which slides in and out the toolbar. The second functionality I achieved successfully, using a view for the whole setup and when the slide button touch up event animates the whole view up and down.

For the scrollview, I wanted to add buttons programmatically, hence I drew an outlet to the class and tried adding a self created button as a subview. However I cannot see the button. Nor can I observe the scrollview sliding.

THe following is the way I'm adding the button:
Also, my total view for the above functionality is very less in size than the total view controller

```
UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] init];

button.titleLabel.text = @"hello";

[_scrollTop setContentSize:self.view.frame.size];

[_scrollTop addSubview:button];
```

The two images down, I hope, should help you understand the functionality I'm trying to develop. If anybody is aware of existence of similar functionality, please do direct me.

[image: Closed]

[image: Opened]

**Edit: Code totally is**

```
    //
//  HCILocationViewController.m
//  app2
//
//  Created by Ravi Vooda on 13/03/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 housing.co.in. All rights reserved.
//

#import "HCILocationViewController.h"
#import "HCIAnnotationViewController.h"

@interface HCILocationViewController ()

@property int widMap;
@property BOOL showExploreOptions;


@end

@implementation HCILocationViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    _mapLocationView.delegate = self;
    MKPointAnnotation *annotation = [[HCIAnnotationViewController alloc]
                                     initwithHouse:[self singleHome]];
    [_mapLocationView addAnnotation:annotation];
    _widMap = 10000;

    _showExploreOptions = NO;

    /*
     UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [button addTarget:self
               action:@selector(aMethod:)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [button setTitle:@"Show View" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 210.0, 160.0, 40.0);//give values whatever you want.
    [_scrollTop addSubview:button];
    */
    [self addButtonsToScrollView];

}

- (void)addButtonsToScrollView
{
    NSInteger buttonCount = 4;

    CGRect buttonFrame = CGRectMake(5.0f, 5.0f, self.scrollTop.frame.size.width-10.0f, 40.0f);

    for (int index = 0; index <buttonCount; index++) {
        UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:buttonFrame];
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [button setTag:index+1];

        NSString *title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Button %d",index+1];
        [button setTitle:title forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        [self.scrollTop addSubview:button];
        buttonFrame.origin.y+=buttonFrame.size.height+5.0f;
    }

    CGSize contentSize = self.scrollTop.frame.size;
    contentSize.height = buttonFrame.origin.y;
    [self.scrollTop setContentSize:contentSize];

}

- (void)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)button
{
    NSLog(@"button pressed");

    switch (button.tag) {
        case 1:
            //Do something
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(MKAnnotationView*) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation {
    NSString *identifier = @"currDetailsIdentifier";
    MKPinAnnotationView *annotationView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[_mapLocationView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:identifier];

    if (annotationView == nil) {
        annotationView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc]
                          initWithAnnotation:annotation
                          reuseIdentifier:identifier];
    } else {
        annotationView.annotation = annotation;
    }

    annotationView.enabled = YES;
    annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;
    return annotationView;
}

-(void) mapViewDidFinishLoadingMap:(MKMapView *)mapView
{

    MKMapRect zoomRect = MKMapRectNull;
    for (id <MKAnnotation> annotation in mapView.annotations) {
        MKMapPoint annotationPoint = MKMapPointForCoordinate(annotation.coordinate);
        MKMapRect pointRect = MKMapRectMake(
                                            annotationPoint.x - (_widMap / 2),
                                            annotationPoint.y - (_widMap/2),
                                            _widMap,
                                            _widMap);
        if (MKMapRectIsNull(zoomRect)) {
            zoomRect = pointRect;
        } else {
            zoomRect = MKMapRectUnion(zoomRect, pointRect);
        }
    }
    [mapView setVisibleMapRect:zoomRect animated:YES];
}

-(void) setMyHouse:(NSDictionary *)singleHouse {
    self.singleHome = singleHouse;
}


- (IBAction)toggleExploreOptionsView:(UIButton *)sender {

    sender.selected = !sender.selected;

    if (_showExploreOptions){
        NSLog(@"Close Options");
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
            _exploreView.frame = CGRectMake(_exploreView.frame.origin.x, _exploreView.frame.origin.y + _exploreOptionsView.frame.size.height, _exploreView.frame.size.width, _exploreView.frame.size.height + _exploreOptionsView.frame.size.height);
        }];
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Open Options");
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
            _exploreView.frame = CGRectMake(_exploreView.frame.origin.x, _exploreView.frame.origin.y - _exploreOptionsView.frame.size.height, _exploreView.frame.size.width, _exploreView.frame.size.height - _exploreOptionsView.frame.size.height);
        }];
    }
    _showExploreOptions = !_showExploreOptions;
}
@end
```

Comment: once post you code here.

Comment: may be problem with scrollview content size once check that one.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly you need to have view which should show up and collapse on a button click event. When the view is shown, it should have a scrollable list of buttons. And you are asking help to show many buttons to scrollView.

[Demo Source Code](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/35012982/Demo%20Projects/TestScrollView.zip)

```
- (void)addButtonsToScrollView
{
    NSInteger buttonCount = 5;

    CGRect buttonFrame = CGRectMake(5.0f, 5.0f, self.scrollTop.frame.size.width-10.0f, 40.0f);

    for (int index = 0; index <buttonCount; index++) {
        UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        [button setFrame:buttonFrame];
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [button setTag:index+1];

        NSString *title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Button %d",index+1];
        [button setTitle:title forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        [self.scrollTop addSubview:button];
        buttonFrame.origin.y+=buttonFrame.size.height+5.0f;
    }

    CGSize contentSize = self.scrollTop.frame.size;
    contentSize.height = buttonFrame.origin.y;
    [self.scrollTop setContentSize:contentSize];

}

- (void)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)button
{
    switch (button.tag) {
        case 1:
            //Do something
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: still not working. And yes thats exactly the functionality I want to develop

Comment: @RaviVooda The view that is shown as your grey area is where you want to put your scrollView rite. Please make sure your scrollView is connected to IBOutlet. You may need to tweak the way titles of buttons otherwise it would work fine

Comment: Yes they are connected. I even tried wit different names, still not working... Not even the buttons are showing up

Comment: @RaviVooda I have included a demo that I tried out. See what you are doing wrong